# How do I XML serialize a list from another class?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a list in a separate class. How do I transfer it to my separate `Serializable` class?

```
[Serializable]
public class ToSerialize
{
//code
}
```

Comment: You make a field (or better property) and assign the list to that. Note: List contents need to be serializable, too. In some scenarios, it would be reasonable to consider to assign a deep clone of the list (think "snapshot") instead of the list itself.

Comment: @Fildor I'm fairly new to c#, so how do I make a list serializable and assign it to a property?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to answer ...

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is:

1. Add a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) to that class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ToSerialize
{
    public List<SomeType> MyList {get; set;}
}
```

2. Assign the list to be serialized to an instance:

```
// somewhere in your code ...
var someList = new List<SomeType>(); // just to clarify what the List should look like
someList.Add(new SomeType()); 
// ...

var output = new ToSerialize();
output.MyList = someList; // assign the list to that property
```

3. Serialize `output`

Note: For the List to be serializable, its contents (i.e. type "SomeType" in above example) need to be serializable.

---

While the above should take you one step further, you later may want to actually not assign the list itself, but a copy of it and its elements. This is commonly referred to as a "deep copy" or "deep clone", sometimes also "snapshot". Just in case you want to do some more research.

Comment: Just as a clarification, This part of the example above

`var output = new ToSerialize();`
`output.MyList = someList;`
throws an error for me because the type var is not specified. Do I replace it with the same variable type as the list I'm trying to convert? And then if that is true, do I assign that list the same way I do with the first one?

Comment: I guess that's about the type parameter (i.e. `List<**TItem**>`). Yes, it has to be the same. The assignment statement wouldn't change, though (`output.MyList = someList;`).